# Create Sub Users / Parent Child Uers

Tags: wordpress, user-management

I am trying to build a site where a family member can create custom posts that only they and other family members can read. The first family member - mom, invites the rest - they can read each others posts, but only edit their own. I understand how plugins like Gravity Forms & Gravity View can help mom register and create & view custom posts - but do you know of a way that she can invite other family members and give them that sub-user control? (Doesn't have to be a GF plugin - just looking for guidance)

Think of the site as a family history blog - where users can only read the posts written by their family.. Many families will register - but only see their posts. Much like BuddyPress Groups - without BuddyPress.

Comment: It can be done but will require custom code. You could use groups to do that. Create a custom post type and then use it in the Group Extension API. https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/group-extension-api/

Comment: You can try a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-manager/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/. It can be done with custom code as @shanebp mentioned, but it's a pretty large and complex amount of work.